# How to bind Emacs key for delete whole word backword as the same in a shell?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have just started learning Linux and Emacs. It was pleasant to have the same key bindings in both Emacs and a shell (bash/tcsh) for the most frequently used cursor movements, so that I do not have to consciously think which one I have to use. Still worse, use the wrong command and undo the mistake. There were two exceptions, though.

One often used command was the equivalent of backspace, delete a character backwards. In a shell, it was `C-h`. I got the same behaviour in Emacs, thanks to this tip from Janos, who probably felt the same way.
http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~komlos/emacs.htm

Now the mistake I do often in Emacs is trying to delete words backwards with the command `M-C-h`, as in a shell.

Can somebody please give a binding that will make Emacs delete words backwards with 'M-C-h'?  Currently, this command selects the whole of the text in a buffer, which is quite an useful thing (`C-a` in windows), but not so frequently used as deleting words backwards.

Moreover, any binding to replace the current binding of `M-h` (from the link above) to help will be appreciated.

Thank you,

Elan.

Comment: What's wrong with the backspace key?

Comment: Nothing, if you are used to it, I guess. I still find it difficult to find the familiar ridges on F and J after jumping out of the home key row. With C-h or C-M-h, with little help from the little finger and thumb, I need not look into the keyboard.

Comment: Also, 'move back' 'delete back' actions can be interleaved with minimal movements, just that of the right forefinger.

Comment: @Elan I lost in reading your question. Could you pin point, which command , which operation. by default C-M-h deletes the backward word.

Comment: Sorry for the long windedness of the description.
C-M-h in a shell deletes a word, backwards.
C-M-h in Emacs, selects the whole text in the buffer (minor mode ido is on, no other modes enabled.)
I am looking for script that binds C-M-h in Emacs to delete backwards one word.

Comment: As an aside, just found that C-Shift-h calls 'help' in Emacs (Rute user's tutorial and exposition says that Control key is insensitive to the case of the character. It seems to hold in this case). So there is no necessity to find a binding to 'help' in Emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below binds C-M h to backward-kill-word. You can put it in your .emacs file.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-h") 'backward-kill-word)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `M-<backspace>` in terminal and emacs to delete word backward.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use key translation so <kbd>C-M-h</kbd> works exactly the same as <kbd>M-backspace</kbd> would in any minor mode (regardless of whether M-backspace is bound to `backward-kill-word` or not).

```
;; bind C-h to <backspace>
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-h] [?\C-?])
;; bind C-M-h to M-<backspace>
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-\M-h] [?\C-\M-?])
```